# I am facing trouble to extract xml tags values

Tags: python, xml

**Problem statement**
I am working on an API. I've saved its response data into an XML file and now wanted to extract data out of it. It's a very big file and having a lot of data tags in it,
but I want to extract a few data and wanted to make its json file for my project on which I am working on.

**Sample xml response is:**

```
    xmlns:meta="http://www.tomtom.com/service/tis/parkingprobabilities/metadata/1.1"
                      schemaVersion="1.1">
    <meta:metaData>
        <meta:creatorUUID>aaac93fc-ba74-102b-b5ef-00304891a58c</meta:creatorUUID>
        <meta:creationTimeUTC>2016-09-30T19:58:01</meta:creationTimeUTC>
        <meta:timeZone>Europe/Berlin</meta:timeZone>
        <meta:cityName>Berlin</meta:cityName>
        <meta:countryCode>DE</meta:countryCode>
        <meta:description>Example showing parking probability and search time profile</meta:description>
    </meta:metaData>
    <roadSegment>
        <uuid>00000000-069f-6d7a-017f-78b7f701185b</uuid>
        <parkingDataProfile>
            <dailyProfile>
                <weekdays>
                    <day>MON</day>
                    <day>TUE</day>
                    <day>WED</day>
                    <day>THU</day>
                    <day>FRI</day>
                </weekdays>
                <hourlyData>
                    <hourOfDay>0</hourOfDay>
                    <parkingProbability>0.10</parkingProbability>
                    <averageSearchTime>12</averageSearchTime>
                </hourlyData>
                <hourlyData>
                    <hourOfDay>1</hourOfDay>
                    <parkingProbability>0.10</parkingProbability>
                    <averageSearchTime>11</averageSearchTime>
                </hourlyData>
                <hourlyData>
                    <hourOfDay>2</hourOfDay>
                    <parkingProbability>0.10</parkingProbability>
                    <averageSearchTime>10</averageSearchTime>
                </hourlyData>
                <!-- usually contains more -->
                <!-- some time slots could be missing -->
                <hourlyData>
                    <hourOfDay>23</hourOfDay>
                    <parkingProbability>0.10</parkingProbability>
                    <averageSearchTime>9</averageSearchTime>
                </hourlyData>
            </dailyProfile>
            <!-- could contain more -->
        </parkingDataProfile>
     </roadSegment>
     <!-- many more -->
</parkingProbabilities>
```

**expected output:**

whole hourly data tags values from each **daily profile node**

**Code tried so far:**

```
from xml.dom import minidom
mydoc = minidom.parse('data_file.xml')

hourly_data = mydoc.getElementsByTagName("hourlyData")
for data in hourly_data:
    print(data.nodeValue)
```

Sorry I am making an unusual mistake.

**Output:**
I am getting **None** printed on screen.

Comment: `hourlyData` has many elements but not `nodeValue`

Comment: how can i access each element and get their values after it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You need to get the actual node to get the data.

```py
from xml.dom import minidom
mydoc = minidom.parse('data_file.xml')

hourly_data = mydoc.getElementsByTagName("hourlyData")
for data in hourly_data:
    print(data.getElementsByTagName("parkingProbability")[0].childNodes[0].data)
    print(data.getElementsByTagName("averageSearchTime")[0].childNodes[0].data)
    print(data.getElementsByTagName("hourOfDay")[0].childNodes[0].data)
```

Comment: thanks for correcting sir. I know was making silly mistake